Socket.io-client in node.js
I want to use socket.io-client cdn in the node js project
Sometimes I do connection to the different socket servers with the different socket io versions. So I need to handle it using socket io client cdns depending on what version I need to use
But the problem it seems the socket.io-client doesn't work properly in the node js environment
When I try to do connection I get timeout errors and thats it
It's an example what cdn I need to use
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.7/socket.io.min.js
Anyone faced this problem? Should I add anything in the cdn directly to make it work?
That's what I've aleady tried. I created a file and then do import from it


/* eslint-disable */
import ws from 'ws'
export default function () {
    // Fix for react-native
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof window.navigator === 'undefined' || typeof window.navigator.userAgent === 'undefined') {
            window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native'
        }
    }
    typeof self == 'undefined'
    && typeof global == 'object'
    && (global.self = global);

    if (typeof self.WebSocket === 'undefined') {
        self.WebSocket = ws
    }

    if (typeof self.navigator === 'undefined') {
        self.navigator = { userAgent: 'node' }
    }

    var t;
    return function e(t, n, r) { // cdn build...



That's how I do import


import io from './versions/v1_3_7.js'

const socket = io()(`${url}`, {...})



I expected it will work but now I get this error trying to run it in node.js
'Error: ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object'

Sorry, the problem was incorrect building
I used vite which sets by default a global object "window"
And then when I test my app it thinks its a browser because of vite...
It's a cdn I use


/* eslint-disable */
import ws from 'ws'

export default function () {
    // Fix for react-native
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof window.navigator === 'undefined' || typeof window.navigator.userAgent === 'undefined') {
            window.navigator.userAgent = 'react-native'
        }
    }

    // Fix for node.js usage
    if (typeof self === 'undefined' && typeof global === 'object') {
        global.self = global

        global.WebSocket = ws

        if (typeof self.navigator === 'undefined') {
            self.navigator = { userAgent: 'node' }
        }
    }

    var t;
    return function e(t, n, r) {



And it's a vite config with specified "ws" package in the external array (to avoid issues with ws which also appeared)


import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig, loadEnv, ConfigEnv } from 'vite'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'

export default ({ mode }: ConfigEnv) => {
    process.env = {
        ...process.env,
        ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')
    }

    return defineConfig({
        build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                external: [ 'ws' ],
                output: {
                    exports: 'named'
                }
            },
            outDir: 'dist',
            sourcemap: true,
            commonjsOptions: {
                esmExternals: true
            },
            lib: {
                entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
                formats: [ 'es', 'cjs', 'umd', 'iife' ],
                name: 'app',
                fileName: (format) => {
                    return `app.${format}.js`
                },
            }
        },
        plugins: [
            dts({
                copyDtsFiles: true,
                rollupTypes: true
            })
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': resolve(__dirname, './src'),
                app: resolve(__dirname, './src'),
            }
        }
    })
}



